Quotient of parabolic subgroup generated by a simple reflection with Borel is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$
In the context of the Demazure resolution, (Bott-Samelson varieties) I have seen the following fact; Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$. Fix a Borel subgroup $B$. Associated to a simple reflection $s_\alpha$ we have a minimal parabolic subgroup $P_{s_\alpha}$ containing $B$.
Then we have $P/B \simeq \mathbb{P}^1$.

I am unsure of the precise definition of $P_{s_\alpha}$. None of the sources I am consulting actually give a refernce.

I can see why this is the case for $GL_n$, as $G/P$ and $G/B$ parametrize partial and complete flags. However I cant see why this is the case in general.

Another related statement I would like to understand is the fact that $G/B$ is fibered over $G/P$ with fibers $\mathbb{P}^1$.


Note that 2. is equivalent to the assertion using a fiber product argument.
I think the result would follow if we could show that $P$ is connected, semi-simple, of rank one. Because then $P$ is isomorphic to $SL_2$, or $PSL_2$ by Springer 7.2.4.

What does it mean for a parabolic subgroup to be "generated" by a reflection? Also, are you working over an algebraically closed field? All in all, more details are needed.

Something is wrong with your definition of $P_\alpha$: in the case of $G=SL(2)$ you get the entire $G$, which is not normally regarded as a parabolic subgroup. Where did you find this definition?

Then I am unsure of the correct definition...

Most likely, this is the normalizer in $G$ of the uniponent subgroup generated by all simple root subgroups excluding the root $\alpha$.

I think the result would follow if we could show that  $P$ is connected, semi-simple, of rank one. Because then $P$ is isomorphic to $SL_2$, or $PSL_2$.
